# Inexplicit 'task' in Chrome Performance DevTools

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome exhibits huge lags when viewing a given web page of mine. I'm using the DevTools *Performance* tab to try and find the culprit which I assume to be somewhere in my JavaScript code.

The following screenshot shows a profile recorded using DevTools. For some of the "tasks" shown in the profile, I can see the details of what the tasks are doing (for example, the one between 8700 ms and 9200 ms is GC), but for other tasks there are no details whatsoever, like the two I have highlighted in the screenshot. How do I figure out what are those tasks doing?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I have the exact same issue. There's obviously a bug in Chrome, actually a regression (I started observing the issue a few days ago). In my case, this happens after my JS reduces the height of a node at the top of the page,  causing the entire rest of the page to move up. That happens instantly (as you'd expect, since everything just needs to move up with no changes inside) and there's no significant time spent in layout; yet, a few ms later, a long task like yours consumes 100% CPU for about 3 seconds with absolutely zero detail in devTools about what it's doing and what triggers it.

Comment: Please star these chromium issues: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=967211 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=967217

Comment: It looks like you might have [JavaScript sampling disabled](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference#disable-js-samples). Enable that option and you should see your JS calls in the **Main** section again.

Comment: @KayceBasques if you are talking to the OP, from his screenshot it can be clearly seen that JavaScript sampling is NOT disabled (you can see the coloured stripes on other tasks except the ones the issue/question is about). In my case, I have double-checked and I don't have it disabled either.

Comment: It's not clear from the screenshot. The colored stripes that you're referring to aren't related to the feature that I'm talking about. I write the DevTools docs. But if you can reproduce the issue you're seeing please file a bug report at https://crbug.com. The DevTools team won't be able to fix the issue unless you provide a URL where they can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @KayceBasques I'm talking about these https://imgur.com/a/gxfGOHE (from the OP). Are those not the details about javascript function calls, that wouldn't be visible if JS sampling were disabled? Anyway, clear or not from the OP's screenshot, I have JS sampling sampling enabled and I see the same as him. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=967217

Comment: This question is [being discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385796/question-closed-because-unclear-edits-accepted-not-reopened?cb=1).

Comment: I found the reason in my code, the continuation of the topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56472959/dom-overload-problems-in-google-chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DOM overload problems in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56472959/dom-overload-problems-in-google-chrome)

Comment: I am having the same issue as well. Safari works perfectly but Chrome is throwing a 3 second 100% CPU System usage with zero details. Chrome BUG!

Answer (score 7):

I ran into a similar issue where I had long, opaque "task" taking several seconds without further information in the Dev Tools.

[image]

A Chrome dev pointed me towards [Perfetto](https://ui.perfetto.dev) (edit: or you can access a built-in similar tool at chrome://tracing). Perfetto lets you record traces of the internals of Chrome. In my case I suspect this was GPU related so I enabled all the gpu* switches:

[image]

and started my trace. After I repro'ed the issue in another tab, I went back to the Perfetto trace. I found these "ThreadControllerImpl::RunTask" slices that seemed to be about the duration of the mysterious system tasks.

[image]

Helpfully Perfetto has an arrow from that task to another group of "slices".

[image]

And each of these is catagorized as "webaudio". From that I learned that my use of AudioContext was likely the culprit, and indeed if I disabled all audio on my page the issue goes away.

[image]

Hopefully this example is illustrative to others trying to solve opaque "system task" issues in Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

You can use JavaScript's performance observer to know the bottleneck of perf issues in your web app.

**Precise code** -

```js
const observer = new PerformanceObserver((list) => {
    console.log('Long Task detected! ️');
    const entries = list.getEntries();
    console.log(entries);
});

observer.observe({entryTypes: ['longtask']});
```

More details [here](https://umaar.com/dev-tips/194-long-tasks/)

Comment: Unfortunately this only shows me the same information as the Profiler tab which isn't particularly useful:. All of my entries have `attribution: [ { name: "unknown" } ]`.