# DOM overload problems in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have some problems when using a large number of hidden items in Google Chrome.

Recently, I [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56329780/inexplicit-task-in-chrome-perfomance-devtools) that many thought was obscure and soon it was closed. I found the cause of this problem, but so far I have no idea how to solve it.

Sometimes when developing pages, a method is used which consists in the fact that some elements are created in advance and hidden, and then displayed if necessary.

So the number of such elements greatly affects the speed of the response of the browser.
Suppose we have the following code:

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName ('Founder') [0];
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName ('Cloud') [0];
var empty = document.getElementsByClassName ('empty') [0];
for (var i = 0; i <50000; i ++) {
var clone = elem.cloneNode (true);
    // var clone = empty.cloneNode (true);
clone.style.display = 'none';
        parent.appendChild (clone);
    }
```

```html
<div class = 'Cloud'>
<input class = 'Founder' type = 'text'>
<div class = 'empty'> </div>
</div>
```

So when I launch it in Firefox (67.0 (64-bit)), then there are no special brakes.
But when I run it in Chrome Version 74.0.3729.169 (Official build), (64 bits), then I get strong brakes.

In the profile this can be seen as the Empty Task (System). Look at the screenshot. (It is from the old theme, and there are a total of 640,000 nodes, but this does not change the essence).

[image: Performance tools showing slow task]

Is there a way to speed up the work, and can I freeze items that are not displayed? As far as I understand these empty tasks, this is the time for which the browser indexes the element or something like that.

Maybe there are any settings that can be changed programmatically, which will speed up the work (may require more RAM).

Comment: I would suggest using some sort of "virtualized" approach to only keep the nodes around that need to be visible.

Comment: Try using [`createDocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inexplicit 'task' in Chrome Performance DevTools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56329780/inexplicit-task-in-chrome-performance-devtools)

Comment: thats only shows the reason of tasks for Chrome in my case.I am left the project when i meet that ,so i dont event try to solve.But i sure the method of preparing a lot of hidden elements dont actual in 2024.U can use reactive frameworks like react,vue to avoid working with hidden html blocks.

Answer (score 2):

`parent.appendChild(...);` is the slow step. You're adding 50,000 nodes to the document, even hidden (which should avoid a reflow layout step) they will be a chunk of work to add.

Adding them to a [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) will help, but not that much if you want to quickly render 640,000 nodes.

Creating elements in advance and then showing them can be a useful way to avoid jank with user interactions, but large documents are generally slower and large numbers of nodes will be hard to make fast.

I think you have two options:

1. Batch the changes into smaller pieces of work, and use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to wait for the next frame to do the next batch. That way will stop jank and the apparent second or so while the browser works on all the new DOM, but will take *much* more time overall. Alternatively you could use [`requestIdleCallback`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestIdleCallback) to build up the massive document in the background when other work isn't happening. With either of these you could have an issue where the document appears interactive but your hidden DOM nodes aren't available yet, so you have to manage that.
2. Switch to adding the DOM as you need it, and instead optimise just that DOM. Create some other object to manage all your data (you could even use a [`Worker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker) or [Comlink](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/comlink) to keep all that data off the main JS thread). This will generally be quicker and is what most apps do, but you will have more work optimising the performance in response to user actions (they might wait 8s for your app to load initially, but then if they click something they're going to expect something within 100ms or so).